# Anaconda python pyinstaller Can not find path ./libtbb.dylib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, anaconda, pyinstaller

Mac OS X 10.13
Anaconda python 2.7.12
pyintaller error

When compiling a script that includes:

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import os
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get the following errors and wwarnings:

```
NameError: name 'FigureManagerWebAgg' is not defined
101543 ERROR: Can not find path ./libtbb.dylib (needed by /Users/barr /anaconda2/lib/libmkl_tbb_thread.dylib)
97784 WARNING: library user32 required via ctypes not found
103993 WARNING: library user32 required via ctypes not found
```

looking in anaconda2/lib the file libtbb.dylib is certainly absent.
Where can I find it to put in anaconda1/lib?

When the executable is run I get the error output below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgres.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 396, in load_module
  File "site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1040, in <module>
  File "site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1043, in Environment
  File "site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 272, in get_supported_platform
  File "site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 478, in get_build_platform
  File "sysconfig.py", line 617, in get_platform
  File "sysconfig.py", line 481, in get_config_vars
  File "sysconfig.py", line 364, in _init_posix
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata
```

The same script is compiled and executed without errors using Anaconda Python on Windows 10 and Ubuntu Linux 16.04 (the same version of Anaconda in all cases).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem recently. I switched to python brew installation instead of Anaconda one.

That solved all problems for me.